# Retrieve error code and message from Google Api Client in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-api-client

I can't find a way to retrieve the HTTP error code and the error message from a call to a Google API using the Google API Client (in Python).
I know the call can raise a HttpError (if it's not a network problem) but that's all I know.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 4):

This is how to access the error details on HttpError in Google API Client(Python):

```
import json
...
except HttpError as e:
    error_reason = json.loads(e.content)['error']['errors'][0]['message']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, found out that `e.resp.status` is where the HTTP error code is stored (`e` being the caught exception). Still don't know how to isolate the error message.

Answer (score 0):

[Class HttpError](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.errors.HttpError-class.html) has a built-in `_get_reason()` method that calculate the reason for the error from the response content. [_get_reason() source code](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.errors-pysrc.html#HttpError._get_reason).
The method has a kind of a misleading name for me. Because I've needed to get the value of the actual `reason` key from a response. Not a `message` key that `_get_reason()` is getting. But the method doing exactly what is asked by Valentin.

Example of a response, decoded from bytes to JSON:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
      "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time(PT).
      You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console:
      https: //console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=908279247468"
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time(PT).
    You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console:
    https: //console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=908279247468"
  }
}
```

Comment: love your answer here it helped me a lot. Worth noting that _get_reason() is a private method on the error object HttpError and should be avoided out of convention. A better way to access would be to access `e['content']['error']['errors'][0]['message']`. Although since e['content'] is a byte string - you will have to parse it as JSON before accessing its properties. In python: `json.loads(e.content)['error']['errors'][0]['message']` if you were using

Answer (score 0):

I found out `HttpError` has a `status_code` property. You can find it [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/googleapiclient/errors.py).

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
...
except HttpError as e:
    print(e.status_code)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `error_details` or `reason` from HttpError in Google API Client(Python):

```
...
except HttpError as e:
    error_reason = e.reason
    error_details = e.error_details # list of dict
...
```